# Parsing multiple tags with no root in nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
fragment = parse("<p></p> <p></p>")
another_node.add_child(fragment)
```

But so far I haven't found anything that does the job - everything wants one root node with multiple children.  Any ideas about how to accomplish this?  It doesn't seem like it's that odd a request, and I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: You could wrap that in a fake root node.

Comment: Sure, that's one backup plan; I'm just curious if there's a way around it.

Comment: Document with multiple top level tags isn't a valid XML. So you shouldn't be expecting XML parser to correctly parse this. :-)

Comment: I'm not claiming it's an entire document though; only a piece of one that will be added in to the real thing.

Comment: This looks like html. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p></p> <p></p>")
another_node = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<div></div>")
another_node.add_child(fragment)
```

Comment: Actually, it is XML, I was just using the p tags for simplicity's sake.  This works with XML too, though.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, too! I was searching everywhere for a solution. Glad I stumbled on this!